# Pass request.session after function is executed

Tags: django, django-sessions

I have app, with authentication and when user logs out, I want a notification message to be displayed. My logout view looks like:

```
def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
    message = 'Logout successfull'
    request.session['message'] = message
    return redirect('index')
```

And my index(the one i'm redirecting to) view looks like:

```
def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.session:
        message = request.session['message']
        context['message'] = message
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

My index.html:

```
{{ message }}
```

Now logged in or out when i go to my index view I see message. When I click on button which logs me out I still see message. I want users only to be able to see messages if they logged out.

I don't know if this is possible and if it isn't then you may tell me another way to pass context with redirect function.

Thanks for help!

Comment: You're assigning the `message` to the session, but you're never clearing it. Clear the message in your `index` view after assigning it to the context.

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans can you write code on how to do that?

Comment: `del request.session['message']`

Comment: @AlexanderSchillemans now I get `KeyError at /` and 
        `message = request.session['message']`  is highlihed.

Comment: If there is no message, you're still trying to access it. See my answer.

Comment: put that delete in a try block. so if the message key is there it will delete it otherwise it will throw an exception but your code will not break, hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Clear the message after you've shown it to the user.

Check if `message` is in the session, if so, a message needs to be displayed.
You're getting a `KeyError` because you're not checking if `message` is inside `request.session` before accessing it.

```py
def index(request):
    context = {}
    if request.session and 'message' in request.session:
        context['message'] = request.session['message']
        del request.session['message']
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Oh I understand so there is actually no message. Then how can I pass one in logout_view?

Comment: @kurac Your code for the logout view should be oke. By doing `request.session['message'] = message`, you're essentially adding the key to the session with the message as value.

Comment: When I print(request.session['message'] in logout view it gives me message, but if i do the same thing in index function it doesn't. It seems like session is not passing? Where could the problem be?